# Create div above parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
  $(this).before('<div class="comment_box_all"><div class="comment_user"></div></div>')
  
});

$('button').click(function(){
    var content = document.createElement("span");
    content.innerHTML = $(".textarea").val().replace(/(\n|\r|\r\n)/g, '<br>');
    $('.comment_user').append(content);
});
```

```css
.comment_panel
{
  width:450px;
  height:100px;
}
textarea
{
  width:300px;
  height:80px;
  }
button
{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:330px;
 }
.comment_box_all
{
  width:450px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#999;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment_panel">
    <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Add text..."></textarea>
    <button>Add comment</button>  
</div>
```

My problem is when click button 'Add comment' create div under `<button>Add comment</button>`

Question: how to do that click button 'Add comment' and create div above `<div class="comment_panel">`. I can't handle with create element above parent div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `.parent` function. You have to  use `.before` method for `comment_panel` div.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().before('<div class="comment_box_all"><div class="comment_user"></div></div>')
    var content = document.createElement("span");
   content.innerHTML=$(".textarea").val().replace(/(\n|\r|\r\n)/g, '<br>');
    $('.comment_user').append(content);
});
```

```css
.comment_panel
{
  width:450px;
  height:100px;
}
textarea
{
  width:300px;
  height:80px;
  }
button
{
  
  top:10px;
  left:330px;
 }
.comment_box_all
{
  width:450px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#999;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment_panel">
    <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Add text..."></textarea>
    <button>Add comment</button>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it's big experience for me:)

Comment: @V.R, I recommend you to use one single `click` event handler, like in my answer.

Comment: @Alexandru-lonut Mihai can I ask you another one question? Is possible to do that if you first click on button and create <div class="comment_box_all"></div> but second and next click (if class="comment_box_all" exist) create only <div class="comment_user"></div> inside class="comment_box_all". And how I can send value form textarea to <div class="comment_user"></div> ?   https://jsfiddle.net/fmxbe6pm/1/

Comment: @Alexandru-lonut Mihai look is option change code on $(this) enent handler because look on updated fiddle, not work good https://jsfiddle.net/fmxbe6pm/4/ (about sending text to div)

Comment: Please take a look now: https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/fmxbe6pm/5/

Comment: graet job, thank you again :) I have started lear JS 2 months ago, I hope I will know it better in future

Comment: @Alexandru-lonut Mihai could look on my fiddle I used your adivices in my  educational application and shows TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined maybe you know solution or any advice? I think that for this error whole script doesn't work property. https://jsfiddle.net/z3a4kzms/1/

Comment: You have no element with class `.op_comm_now`, and the panel returns `undefined` so that's why cannot recognize `replace`

Comment: button has class .op_comm_now

Comment: You have used wrong `js`. You doesn't have to use `click` event inside another click event

Comment: yes I saw that, changed it on one('click') like you had in previous codes now is better but something still is wrong https://jsfiddle.net/z3a4kzms/3/ but thanks for your help, I will win this fight :)

Comment: I solved this problem, I should add class for <textarea>, but I don't understand why can't use find('.classname textarea'), thanks for all